# JUnit assertFalse(false) can't find BooleanSupplier

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I am attempting to test an library I am designing using JUnit5. I have come to the point where I need to assert something is false however Gradle is running into errors whenever I attempt to use `assertFalse(...)`.

I am using JUnit 5.2 with Gradle 5.1.1 and have tried the assertFalse() method signatures that fit my needs to no avail. This includes just with a boolean condition, with a condition plus a message, using `Assertions.assertFalse(...)` to remove the static import, etc.

I have been able to narrow down the code to just a simple test. The code below fails:

```java
@Test
void test(){
    assertFalse(false);
}
```

My imports are:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertFalse;

//plus some others from the library
```

Gradle gives an error of:

```
ProjectDir/FTC_Robot_API/TeamCode
/src/test/java/org/firstinspires/ftc/teamcode/FTC_Library/Robot
/RobotBaseTest.java:28: error: cannot access BooleanSupplier
        assertFalse(false);
        ^
  class file for java.util.function.BooleanSupplier not found
1 error
```

It is my hope that what is obviously a boolean (`false`) is not a BooleanSupplier so I am stuck with regards to why it is giving me this error. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is it reproducible with new sample project?

Comment: @y.bedrov Does not appear so, just created a new project with the same dependency `testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.2.0'` and it didn't have any trouble

Comment: Have you tried to run "File | Invalidate Caches" and then "Refresh" from Gradle tool window?

Comment: @y.bedrov Nope. Still gives the same error :/

Comment: Please try to remove all IDE related data (.iml file and .idea folder) and reimport project.

Comment: @y.bedrov Believe it or not, it still gives the same error. I really don't know what to tell you :I

Comment: not working even after removing all the files of ide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue when using IntelliJ. To resolve it

1. Remove IntelliJ project files (e.g. `.iml`  and `.idea` files)
2. Close the project
3. From the IntelliJ Welcome Screen select "Import Project"

[image]

4. Select "Project from Existing Sources"
5. Follow the prompts to set up the project. For more see the IntelliJ website: jetbrains.com/help/idea/import-project-or-module-wizard.html